# Are there finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebras which are not Banach algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

[It is known](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~moslehian/cfa/BA12.PDF) that not every algebra (over a ground field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is a [Banach algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra). It might be a silly question, but are there examples of finite dimensional ($\mathbb{R}$- or $\mathbb{C}$-)algebras which are not Banach algebras (i.e. for which no submultiplicative norm exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every finite dimensional unitary algebra $A$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb R)$. Retricting the norm of the latter gives a norm on $A$.

Comment: This is what I was starting to think. Can you give a reference or short proof as to why such an isomorphism always exists?

Comment: @Bib-lost: You can embed $A$ in $End(A)$ since $A$ acts on itself by multiplication.

Comment: Ok, got it to work, thanks!

Comment: Is this result, a formulation of the Wedderburn-Mal'tsev theorem?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's clear that in the finite-dimensional case multiplication is going to be continuous with respect to any norm, just as any linear transformation is bounded. If so then any norm is going to satisfy $||xy||\le c||x||\,||y||$, and then $|||x|||=c||x||$ is submultiplicative.

Comment: @user43208 I always get that backwards - thanks.